# If $P(A\setminus B)\geq P(B\setminus A)$, then $P(A) \leq P(B):\;$ Why false?

Tags: probability-theory

If $P(A\setminus B)\geq P(B\setminus A)$, then $P(A) \leq P(B)$.

I know that it's false using common sense but how do I show that statistically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$P(A)=P(A\cap B)+\underline{\qquad}\qquad P(B)=P(A\cap B)+\underline{\qquad}$$

Comment: $$P(A)=P(A\cap B)+ P(A\setminus B). P(B)=P(A\cap B)+P(B\setminus A)$$. Then since $P(A\setminus B)\geq P(B\setminus A)$, $P(A)\geq P(B)$. Thanks

Comment: Yep. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

$\left(A\backslash B\right)\cup\left(A\cap B\right)=A$ and $\left(A\backslash B\right)\cap\left(A\cap B\right)=\emptyset$

$\left(B\backslash A\right)\cup\left(A\cap B\right)=B$ and $\left(B\backslash A\right)\cap\left(A\cap B\right)=\emptyset$